# Is there an event that let's me know if an SD Card is mounted? Have to copy several hundred Cards

Tags: c#, windows, sd-card

Is there a Windows Event or mechanism that I can use to know if an SD Card is mounted on a PC running Windows XP/ Vista /7 in C#?

Up to today I found a way to use WM Messages to know if a new Drive is connected and also a way with WQL  and they work fine for CD / DVD and USB but none was able to detect if I inserted a SD Card into the PC. This seems to be different from USB Drives and I guess that is because the "Reader" Hardware is already attached to the PC.

But I can't believe that there is no way:(

A bit background to my Question:

I have to copy 800 SD Cards by Hand, that's a one Time thing, and I want to make a little application that starts the copyjob as soon as I insert a card so that you don't have to click any buttons.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe an alternative solution:

There's a guide how to register your app as an auto-play handler [on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15626/Implement-an-Autoplay-Handler). You could then check the box telling windows to always use this action and there you go.

**Edit:**

Another approach would be to use the DriveDetector class also introduced [on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program). This class will automatically notify you about arrived or removed drives, but I'm not sure if this works for flash cards.

Comment: DriveDetector is working for usb drive but not working for SD Card

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Windows 7 has autoplay disabled for all drives except CD/DVD/BD.

Were I you, this is what I would do:

1. Get a list of files from the target drive (let's assume it's always the same drive) using this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/directory-getfiles
2. If the list is 0 length (ie, no files) then assume nothing is mounted
3. If the list is not 0 length, copy files.

Comment: but if I insert a SD Card the Autoplay Windows Pops Up on my Windows 7?!